# install4j: Changing pref_jre.cfg on MacOS doesn't work

Tags: install4j

We use install4j for our software and we have our own autoupdate procedure (which perform update of JRE too). We try to change the location of JRE using pref_jre.cfg. On Windows it is working as expected - running our application with `/create-i4j-log` tells that JRE folder is the same as in `pref_jre.cfg`. But on MacOS it doesn't work. E.g. if I rename `jre.bundle` in `.install4j` folder to `v2.jre.bundle`, than change `pref_jre.cfg` appropriately, than run with `INSTALL4J_LOG=yes` - the log says that JRE is `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home` that is not that I expect.

Can installj4 on MacOS use path to JRE defined in `pref_jre.cfg`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, this is currently not implemented on macOS. A workaround is to create a symbolic link from `.install4j/jre.bundle` to the JRE that should be used.

In the case of a single bundle, the link should be created in `Contents/Resources/jre.bundle`.

Comment: Ingo, could you please clarify from witch version of install4j launcher (*.exe file) `pref_jre.cfg` is used?

Comment: There is only one such file per installation, in `.install4j\pref_jre.cfg`